# Connection between server and android

Tags: java, android, sockets, http, instant-messaging

I'm trying to develop an app for instant messaging (like whatsapp). I'm very confused about what type of connection i should use: socket, http or other? Do i have to use non-standard java API?  For server i use java and for client i use andoid (java).
I have already tried socket connection but without success. I don't get error but nothing happens because the device and the server are not connected(i don't know why).

This is my client class (android) that sends messages:

```
public class SendMsg implements Runnable {

private Socket socket;
String msg;

public SendMsg(String msg){
    this.msg=msg;
    }

@Override
public void run() {


    try {
        socket = new Socket("ip_globale_server",5000);
        socket.setSoTimeout(5000);
        BufferedWriter writer= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        writer.write(msg);
        writer.flush();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.err.println("Connection error");
    }
    finally{
        if (socket!=null) {
        try{socket.close();}
        catch(IOException e){}
        }
    }

}
}
```

this is my java server class that waits for connection:

```
public class ReceiveMsg implements Runnable {

ServerSocket server= null;
Socket connection=null;
InputStream in;
InputStreamReader inr;
StringBuilder smsg;


public void run() {
    System.out.print("Server has started");

    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(5000);
        System.out.println("I'm waiting for connection");
        connection = server.accept();
        System.out.println("I'm connected with "+ connection.toString());
        in = connection.getInputStream();
        inr = new InputStreamReader(in,"ASCII");
        for (int c= inr.read();c!=-1; c= inr.read()){
            smsg.append((char)c);
        }

        //this class is for storing the message
        new Store (smsg.toString(),1,2);

    }
    catch(IOException ex){}
    finally {
        try{
        if (server != null)
            server.close();

        if (server != null)
            server.close();

        }
        catch(IOException e){

        }
    }
```

Could you help me to get start please.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: why don't you use Google Cloud Messaging for instant messaging

Comment: With Google Cloud messaging, Can you send only messages or file too?

Comment: you can only send 4 kb of text message. for downloading a file, you could just send him the link to file and let the client side take care of the downloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely suggest using `Google Cloud Messaging` here. This has the benefit that once a device runs your app, you can make it register against `GCM` and you can send them the messages as needed, this way you don't have to struggle with sockets that close after a certain amount of time.

This approach would need that you have to implement some server (for instance, a web server with PHP) and make the users communicate with it, so the flow would be:

1. Your server sends a broadcast message to all registered devices telling them they have to register against the `GCM` service.
2. The devices get the message, and you implement the `BroadcastReceiver` to get both latitude and longitude and send it to your remote server, say `http://www.mysuperserver.com/getmsg.php`, via a `POST` request.
3. Your server processes the parameters and you save them or do whatever you need.

If you want to follow this approach, this are the steps you have to follow:

1. Go to https://console.developers.google.com. With your Google account, register a new project. This will provide you an API key and a Sender ID.
2. You'll need to make the device register against your project in `GCM`. You can achieve this by importing `Google Play Services` within your project, and once done, do something alike to this:

   ```
   GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
   final String regid = gcm.register("YOUR_SENDER_ID");
   ```
3. At this time, the `GCM` server already knows that this user has registered whithin your project and has given him a `regid`.
4. The next step is informing your own remote server that the user has done so, and save somewhere the `regid` that it has been given, so you can later send them messages. So in the client side, make a `HTTP POST` request against your server sending that `regid` and process it with somethat like this:

   ```
   $regid = $_POST['regid'];

   if (($regId) && ($ipAddr))
     sql_query("INSERT INTO gcm_subscribers(regid) VALUES($regid')");
   ```
5. Once done, you know who have already registered against your database. You can `SELECT` all the users and send them the new messages (simulating a multicast behavior).

   ```
   function sendNotification($registrationIdsArray, $messageData) {
     $apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY";

     $headers = array("Content-Type:" . "application/json", "Authorization:" . "key=" . $apiKey);
     $data = array(
       'data' => $messageData,
       'registration_ids' => $registrationIdsArray
     );

     $ch = curl_init();

     curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
     curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send" );
     curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
     curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
     curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
     curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data) );

     $response = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);

     return $response;
   }
   ```
6. Once in your client, just process that `GCM` message and display it accordingly. To process the messages I'm including a few links below.

More about this:

- Reference on [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html)
- [Android Push Notifications using Google Cloud Messaging GCM - Android Example](http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139)
- [Google Cloud Messaging using PHP](http://distriqt.com/post/1273)
- [Connection between PHP (server) and Android (client) Using HTTP and JSON](http://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/connection-between-php-server-and-android-client-using-http-and-json/)
- [Notificaciones Push Android: Google Cloud Messaging (GCM). Implementación Cliente (Nueva Versión)](http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/?p=4126) (spanish)

Comment: Thank you you're answer is really useful, i can't vote up it because i have a little reputation. i'm sorry

Comment: No problem about that, just accept the answer that helped you most once you decide which approach to use, by clicking on the tick on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Push Notifications. If you use sockets, the connection will terminate at some point and you'll not be able to keep receiving messages.

Answer (score 0):

For instant messages in android you should use Google Cloud Messaging.

Introduction:

```
  http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html
```

Getting Started:

```
  http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Your client is trying to connect to "ip_globale_server". Try using your servers ip address instead. Also make sure your phone and server are on the same network. If your phone is on 3g it will not be able to connect to your local development server.

Apart from that i agree with the others about gcm

Comment: i have decided that i'll use gmc. anyway thank you for your answer.

Comment: Yes you should use gcm. There are some cases thought where you can't. For example if you want to transfer data larger than 4k (eg. an image). Also there is no way to know if the client got a msg with gcm so in that case your client should notify the server when it does.

Comment: Can i use two servers one for ftp (send media like photo, video), the other GMC?